# How to use FaceBook API?

Tags: iphone

i am using Facebook API tutorial.It's working perfectly but whenever i send the wall to Facebook its showing "Connect to Punjabi Adda" as an link in my Facebook account.How can change it? If someone have idea please tell me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raman,

In the `postToWall` method

change the string in `dialog.attachment`.

I hope it helps